# cannot read property 'split' in jquery using add header active link

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

In jquery I can't read the property 'split' which is in header active link.I added my code below with a snippet. Please some one help me to figure the problem and solve it.

Here is my snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = $(location).attr('href');
  var parts = url.split("/");
  var last_part = parts[parts.length - 1];
  $("li").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    var parts = link.split("/");

    if (last_part == parts[parts.length - 1]) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index"><img src="/resources/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></img>
        </a>
        <span class="" style="margin-left:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;margin-top:18px;text-transform:uppercase;cursor:pointer"> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:14px; font-weight:600">
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/views/index.jsp">Home</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/views/features.jsp">Features</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/views/services.jsp">Services</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/views/pricing.jsp">Pricing</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/blog/blog?page=1">Blog</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="/views/contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Still I have no idea what might be the problem

Comment: how i solve this error

Comment: Please edit and clarify your problem.

Comment: this code is working but i am getting this error

Comment: Highly we recommend you to mention the problem so clearly which will be helpful to give a solution

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are using jQuery 1.6 or above*, the problem is likely in

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var parts = url.split("/");
```

`location` is an object with an `href` property; it is not a DOM element, and it does not have an `href` attribute. From the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

You could instead try

```
var parts = location.href.split("/");
```

or, if you really want to stick with jQuery,

```
var parts = $(location).prop("href").split("/");
```

Comment: thanks for answering me...exactly hear i am creating one separate header page and common for all pages my code is working but I am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.the error shows in console-source "var parts = link.split("/");"